# Flutter APK builds in the phone, but not able to open?

Tags: android, flutter

[enter link description here](https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/cybrillatest-ad60b.appspot.com/o/VID_20180517_142856.mp4?alt=media&token=464971fa-d689-440d-b869-c518197ce684)I am running the app on Redmi 4. I've just created a Flutter project and I am running the starter app.but its not opening. When I open the app, it opens and suddenly closes. When I run Flutter Doctor there are no issues. [check this video](https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/cybrillatest-ad60b.appspot.com/o/VID_20180517_142856.mp4?alt=media&token=464971fa-d689-440d-b869-c518197ce684)

```
     O:\flutter projects\shout>flutter doctor
     Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
     [√] Flutter (Channel master, v0.3.7-pre.12, on Microsoft Windows 
     [Version 10.0.10240], locale en-US)
     [√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 
      27.0.3)
       [√] Android Studio (version 3.0)
   [√] Connected devices (1 available)

  • No issues found!
```

```
:\flutter projects\shout>flutter run -v
[  +42 ms] [O:\FlutterSDK\flutter\] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref -- 
symbolic @{u}
[  +55 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[        ] origin/master
[   +2 ms] [O:\FlutterSDK\flutter\] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[  +27 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[        ] master
[   +2 ms] [O:\FlutterSDK\flutter\] git ls-remote --get-url origin
[  +24 ms] Exit code 0 from: git ls-remote --get-url origin
[        ] https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
[   +2 ms] [O:\FlutterSDK\flutter\] git log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[  +23 ms] Exit code 0 from: git log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[        ] 78e205c8f2477ba3cdd7fbe6394a6c14bf6dd187
[   +2 ms] [O:\FlutterSDK\flutter\] git log -n 1 --pretty=format:%ar
[  +22 ms] Exit code 0 from: git log -n 1 --pretty=format:%ar
[        ] 2 hours ago
[   +2 ms] [O:\FlutterSDK\flutter\] git describe --match v*.*.* --first- 
 parent --long --tags
[  +28 ms] Exit code 0 from: git describe --match v*.*.* --first-parent -- 
long --tags
[        ] v0.4.4-32-g78e205c8f
[ +283 ms] C:\Users\shijo\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb 

devices -l [  +16 ms] Exit code 0 from:
C:\Users\shijo\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb devices
-l [        ] List of devices attached
           437122857d74           device product:santoni model:Redmi_4 
Launching lib/main.dart on Redmi 4 in debug mode... [   +9 ms]
Initializing gradle... [        ] Using gradle from O:\flutter
projects\shout\android\gradlew.bat. [  +72 ms] O:\flutter
projects\shout\android\gradlew.bat -v [ +766 ms]
           ------------------------------------------------------------
           Gradle 4.1
           ------------------------------------------------------------

           Build time:   2017-08-07 14:38:48 UTC
           Revision:     941559e020f6c357ebb08d5c67acdb858a3defc2

           Groovy:       2.4.11
           Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.6 compiled on June 29 2015
           JVM:          1.8.0_152-release (JetBrains s.r.o 25.152-b01)
           OS:           Windows 10 10.0 amd64
         [   +3 ms] Resolving dependencies...
       [   +1 ms] [android\] O:\flutter projects\shout\android\gradlew.bat 
      app:properties
      [+2020 ms] :app:properties

           ------------------------------------------------------------
           Project :app
           ------------------------------------------------------------

           allprojects: [project ':app']
           android: com.android.build.gradle.AppExtension_Decorated@453f7681
           androidDependencies: task ':app:androidDependencies'
           ant: org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultAntBuilder@1b5bc337
           antBuilderFactory: 
           org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultAntBuilderFactory@3db546bc
           archivesBaseName: app
           artifacts: 



    org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.DefaultArtifactHandler_Decorated@4a1452f2
           asDynamicObject: DynamicObject for project ':app'
           assemble: task ':app:assemble'
           assembleAndroidTest: task ':app:assembleAndroidTest'
           assembleDebug: task ':app:assembleDebug'
           assembleDebugAndroidTest: task ':app:assembleDebugAndroidTest'
           assembleDebugUnitTest: task ':app:assembleDebugUnitTest'
           assembleProfile: task ':app:assembleProfile'
           assembleProfileUnitTest: task ':app:assembleProfileUnitTest'
           assembleRelease: task ':app:assembleRelease'
           assembleReleaseUnitTest: task ':app:assembleReleaseUnitTest'
           baseClassLoaderScope: org.gradle.api.internal.initialization.DefaultClassLoaderScope@74a1be4f
           buildDependents: task ':app:buildDependents'
           buildDir: O:\flutter projects\shout\build\app
           buildFile: O:\flutter projects\shout\android\app\build.gradle
           buildNeeded: task ':app:buildNeeded'
           buildOutputs: BaseVariantOutput container
           buildScriptSource: org.gradle.groovy.scripts.UriScriptSource@31a69997
           buildscript: org.gradle.api.internal.initialization.DefaultScriptHandler@26b1a9b9
           bundleAppClassesDebug: task ':app:bundleAppClassesDebug'
           bundleAppClassesDebugAndroidTest: task ':app:bundleAppClassesDebugAndroidTest'
           bundleAppClassesDebugUnitTest: task ':app:bundleAppClassesDebugUnitTest'
           bundleAppClassesProfile: task ':app:bundleAppClassesProfile'
           bundleAppClassesProfileUnitTest: task ':app:bundleAppClassesProfileUnitTest'
           bundleAppClassesRelease: task ':app:bundleAppClassesRelease'
           bundleAppClassesReleaseUnitTest: task ':app:bundleAppClassesReleaseUnitTest'
           check: task ':app:check'
           checkDebugManifest: task ':app:checkDebugManifest'
           checkProfileManifest: task ':app:checkProfileManifest'
           checkReleaseManifest: task ':app:checkReleaseManifest'
           childProjects: {}
           class: class org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject_Decorated
           classLoaderScope: org.gradle.api.internal.initialization.DefaultClassLoaderScope@4e5aec5f
           cleanBuildCache: task ':app:cleanBuildCache'
           compileDebugAidl: task ':app:compileDebugAidl'
           compileDebugAndroidTestAidl: task ':app:compileDebugAndroidTestAidl'
           compileDebugAndroidTestJavaWithJavac: task ':app:compileDebugAndroidTestJavaWithJavac'
           compileDebugAndroidTestNdk: task ':app:compileDebugAndroidTestNdk'
           compileDebugAndroidTestRenderscript: task ':app:compileDebugAndroidTestRenderscript'
           compileDebugAndroidTestShaders: task ':app:compileDebugAndroidTestShaders'
           compileDebugAndroidTestSources: task ':app:compileDebugAndroidTestSources'
           compileDebugJavaWithJavac: task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'
           compileDebugNdk: task ':app:compileDebugNdk'
           compileDebugRenderscript: task ':app:compileDebugRenderscript'
           compileDebugShaders: task ':app:compileDebugShaders'
           compileDebugSources: task ':app:compileDebugSources'
           compileDebugUnitTestJavaWithJavac: task ':app:compileDebugUnitTestJavaWithJavac'
           compileDebugUnitTestSources: task ':app:compileDebugUnitTestSources'
           compileLint: task ':app:compileLint'
           compileProfileAidl: task ':app:compileProfileAidl'
           compileProfileJavaWithJavac: task ':app:compileProfileJavaWithJavac'
           compileProfileNdk: task ':app:compileProfileNdk'
           compileProfileRenderscript: task ':app:compileProfileRenderscript'
           compileProfileShaders: task ':app:compileProfileShaders'
           compileProfileSources: task ':app:compileProfileSources'
           compileProfileUnitTestJavaWithJavac: task ':app:compileProfileUnitTestJavaWithJavac'
           compileProfileUnitTestSources: task ':app:compileProfileUnitTestSources'
           compileReleaseAidl: task ':app:compileReleaseAidl'
           compileReleaseJavaWithJavac: task ':app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'
           compileReleaseNdk: task ':app:compileReleaseNdk'
           compileReleaseRenderscript: task ':app:compileReleaseRenderscript'
           compileReleaseShaders: task ':app:compileReleaseShaders'
           compileReleaseSources: task ':app:compileReleaseSources'
           compileReleaseUnitTestJavaWithJavac: task ':app:compileReleaseUnitTestJavaWithJavac'
           compileReleaseUnitTestSources: task ':app:compileReleaseUnitTestSources'
           components: SoftwareComponentInternal set
           configurationActions: org.gradle.configuration.project.DefaultProjectConfigurationActionContainer@37f0701d
           configurationTargetIdentifier: org.gradle.configuration.ConfigurationTargetIdentifier$1@321f2d55
           configurations: configuration container
           connectedAndroidTest: task ':app:connectedAndroidTest'
           connectedCheck: task ':app:connectedCheck'
           connectedDebugAndroidTest: task ':app:connectedDebugAndroidTest'
           consumeConfigAttr: task ':app:consumeConfigAttr'
           convention: org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultConvention@1948b6ce
           copyFlutterAssetsDebug: task ':app:copyFlutterAssetsDebug'
           copyFlutterAssetsProfile: task ':app:copyFlutterAssetsProfile'
           copyFlutterAssetsRelease: task ':app:copyFlutterAssetsRelease'
           createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests: task ':app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests'
           createProfileCompatibleScreenManifests: task ':app:createProfileCompatibleScreenManifests'
           createReleaseCompatibleScreenManifests: task ':app:createReleaseCompatibleScreenManifests'
           defaultArtifacts: org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultArtifactPublicationSet_Decorated@e989ac
           defaultTasks: []
           deferredProjectConfiguration: org.gradle.api.internal.project.DeferredProjectConfiguration@34ad6134
           dependencies: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler_Decorated@7f139771
           depth: 1
           description: null
           deviceAndroidTest: task ':app:deviceAndroidTest'
           deviceCheck: task ':app:deviceCheck'
           displayName: project ':app'
           distsDir: O:\flutter projects\shout\build\app\distributions
           distsDirName: distributions
           docsDir: O:\flutter projects\shout\build\app\docs
           docsDirName: docs
           ext: org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultExtraPropertiesExtension@2331b09b
           extensions: org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultConvention@1948b6ce
           extractProguardFiles: task ':app:extractProguardFiles'
           fileOperations: org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultFileOperations@6fd9f9b8
           fileResolver: org.gradle.api.internal.file.BaseDirFileResolver@302291b6
           flutter: FlutterExtension_Decorated@53e920dc
           flutterBuildDebug: task ':app:flutterBuildDebug'
           flutterBuildProfile: task ':app:flutterBuildProfile'
           flutterBuildRelease: task ':app:flutterBuildRelease'
           flutterBuildX86Jar: task ':app:flutterBuildX86Jar'
           generateDebugAndroidTestAssets: task ':app:generateDebugAndroidTestAssets'
           generateDebugAndroidTestBuildConfig: task ':app:generateDebugAndroidTestBuildConfig'
           generateDebugAndroidTestResValues: task ':app:generateDebugAndroidTestResValues'
           generateDebugAndroidTestResources: task ':app:generateDebugAndroidTestResources'
           generateDebugAndroidTestSources: task ':app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources'
           generateDebugAssets: task ':app:generateDebugAssets'
           generateDebugBuildConfig: task ':app:generateDebugBuildConfig'
           generateDebugResValues: task ':app:generateDebugResValues'
           generateDebugResources: task ':app:generateDebugResources'
           generateDebugSources: task ':app:generateDebugSources'
           generateProfileAssets: task ':app:generateProfileAssets'
           generateProfileBuildConfig: task ':app:generateProfileBuildConfig'
           generateProfileResValues: task ':app:generateProfileResValues'
           generateProfileResources: task ':app:generateProfileResources'
           generateProfileSources: task ':app:generateProfileSources'
           generateReleaseAssets: task ':app:generateReleaseAssets'
           generateReleaseBuildConfig: task ':app:generateReleaseBuildConfig'
           generateReleaseResValues: task ':app:generateReleaseResValues'
           generateReleaseResources: task ':app:generateReleaseResources'
           generateReleaseSources: task ':app:generateReleaseSources'
           gradle: build 'android'
           group: android
           identityPath: :app
           inheritedScope: org.gradle.api.internal.ExtensibleDynamicObject$InheritedDynamicObject@7df2f752
           installDebug: task ':app:installDebug'
           installDebugAndroidTest: task ':app:installDebugAndroidTest'
           installProfile: task ':app:installProfile'
           installRelease: task ':app:installRelease'
           javaPreCompileDebug: task ':app:javaPreCompileDebug'
           javaPreCompileDebugAndroidTest: task ':app:javaPreCompileDebugAndroidTest'
           javaPreCompileDebugUnitTest: task ':app:javaPreCompileDebugUnitTest'
           javaPreCompileProfile: task ':app:javaPreCompileProfile'
           javaPreCompileProfileUnitTest: task ':app:javaPreCompileProfileUnitTest'
           javaPreCompileRelease: task ':app:javaPreCompileRelease'
           javaPreCompileReleaseUnitTest: task ':app:javaPreCompileReleaseUnitTest'
           layout: org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultProjectLayout@5d46c56d
           libsDir: O:\flutter projects\shout\build\app\libs
           libsDirName: libs
           lint: task ':app:lint'
           lintDebug: task ':app:lintDebug'
           lintProfile: task ':app:lintProfile'
           lintRelease: task ':app:lintRelease'
           lintVitalRelease: task ':app:lintVitalRelease'
           logger: org.gradle.internal.logging.slf4j.OutputEventListenerBackedLogger@21245cdf
           logging: org.gradle.internal.logging.services.DefaultLoggingManager@79cd4052
           mergeDebugAndroidTestAssets: task ':app:mergeDebugAndroidTestAssets'
           mergeDebugAndroidTestJniLibFolders: task ':app:mergeDebugAndroidTestJniLibFolders'
           mergeDebugAndroidTestResources: task ':app:mergeDebugAndroidTestResources'
           mergeDebugAndroidTestShaders: task ':app:mergeDebugAndroidTestShaders'
           mergeDebugAssets: task ':app:mergeDebugAssets'
           mergeDebugJniLibFolders: task ':app:mergeDebugJniLibFolders'
           mergeDebugResources: task ':app:mergeDebugResources'
           mergeDebugShaders: task ':app:mergeDebugShaders'
           mergeProfileAssets: task ':app:mergeProfileAssets'
           mergeProfileJniLibFolders: task ':app:mergeProfileJniLibFolders'
           mergeProfileResources: task ':app:mergeProfileResources'
           mergeProfileShaders: task ':app:mergeProfileShaders'
           mergeReleaseAssets: task ':app:mergeReleaseAssets'
           mergeReleaseJniLibFolders: task ':app:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders'
           mergeReleaseResources: task ':app:mergeReleaseResources'
           mergeReleaseShaders: task ':app:mergeReleaseShaders'
           mockableAndroidJar: task ':app:mockableAndroidJar'
           modelRegistry: org.gradle.model.internal.registry.DefaultModelRegistry@63386077
           modelSchemaStore: org.gradle.model.internal.manage.schema.extract.DefaultModelSchemaStore@43c64b72
           module: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ProjectBackedModule@3ab94e72
           name: app
           normalization: org.gradle.normalization.internal.DefaultInputNormalizationHandler_Decorated@91a4325
           objects: org.gradle.api.internal.model.DefaultObjectFactory@3f2e2644
           org.gradle.jvmargs: -Xmx1536M
           packageDebug: task ':app:packageDebug'
           packageDebugAndroidTest: task ':app:packageDebugAndroidTest'
           packageProfile: task ':app:packageProfile'
           packageRelease: task ':app:packageRelease'
           parent: root project 'android'
           parentIdentifier: root project 'android'
           path: :app
           platformAttrExtractor: task ':app:platformAttrExtractor'
           pluginManager: org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager_Decorated@621c82c6
           plugins: [org.gradle.api.plugins.HelpTasksPlugin@5d5a7f77,
com.android.build.gradle.api.AndroidBasePlugin@5dd17416,
org.gradle.language.base.plugins.LifecycleBasePlugin@1e7d556f,
org.gradle.api.plugins.BasePlugin@51e2cc5f,
org.gradle.api.plugins.ReportingBasePlugin@1a09eb00,
org.gradle.platform.base.plugins.ComponentBasePlugin@3c9f5505,
org.gradle.language.base.plugins.LanguageBasePlugin@691be87d,
org.gradle.platform.base.plugins.BinaryBasePlugin@5295736a,
org.gradle.api.plugins.JavaBasePlugin@229df085,
com.android.build.gradle.internal.coverage.JacocoPlugin@56de1a1b,
com.android.build.gradle.AppPlugin@10f96d89, FlutterPlugin@2be9a14a]
           preBuild: task ':app:preBuild'
           preDebugAndroidTestBuild: task ':app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild'
           preDebugBuild: task ':app:preDebugBuild'
           preDebugUnitTestBuild: task ':app:preDebugUnitTestBuild'
           preProfileBuild: task ':app:preProfileBuild'
           preProfileUnitTestBuild: task ':app:preProfileUnitTestBuild'
           preReleaseBuild: task ':app:preReleaseBuild'
           preReleaseUnitTestBuild: task ':app:preReleaseUnitTestBuild'
           prepareLintJar: task ':app:prepareLintJar'
           processDebugAndroidTestJavaRes: task ':app:processDebugAndroidTestJavaRes'
           processDebugAndroidTestManifest: task ':app:processDebugAndroidTestManifest'
           processDebugAndroidTestResources: task ':app:processDebugAndroidTestResources'
           processDebugJavaRes: task ':app:processDebugJavaRes'
           processDebugManifest: task ':app:processDebugManifest'
           processDebugResources: task ':app:processDebugResources'
           processDebugUnitTestJavaRes: task ':app:processDebugUnitTestJavaRes'
           processOperations: org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultFileOperations@6fd9f9b8
           processProfileJavaRes: task ':app:processProfileJavaRes'
           processProfileManifest: task ':app:processProfileManifest'
           processProfileResources: task ':app:processProfileResources'
           processProfileUnitTestJavaRes: task ':app:processProfileUnitTestJavaRes'
           processReleaseJavaRes: task ':app:processReleaseJavaRes'
           processReleaseManifest: task ':app:processReleaseManifest'
           processReleaseResources: task ':app:processReleaseResources'
           processReleaseUnitTestJavaRes: task ':app:processReleaseUnitTestJavaRes'
           project: project ':app'
           projectConfigurator: org.gradle.api.internal.project.BuildOperationCrossProjectConfigurator@71c09107
           projectDir: O:\flutter projects\shout\android\app
           projectEvaluationBroadcaster: ProjectEvaluationListener broadcast
           projectEvaluator: org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator@515b7c90
           projectPath: :app
           projectRegistry: org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectRegistry@a830ef5
           properties: {...}
           providers: org.gradle.api.internal.provider.DefaultProviderFactory@5aceccea
           reporting: org.gradle.api.reporting.ReportingExtension_Decorated@c0fb7d1
           reportsDir: O:\flutter projects\shout\build\app\reports
           repositories: repository container
           resolveConfigAttr: task ':app:resolveConfigAttr'
           resources: org.gradle.api.internal.resources.DefaultResourceHandler@793247fe
           rootDir: O:\flutter projects\shout\android
           rootProject: root project 'android'
           scriptHandlerFactory: org.gradle.api.internal.initialization.DefaultScriptHandlerFactory@73871bb4
           scriptPluginFactory: org.gradle.configuration.ScriptPluginFactorySelector@61615797
           serviceRegistryFactory: org.gradle.internal.service.scopes.ProjectScopeServices$4@1021c555
           services: ProjectScopeServices
           signingReport: task ':app:signingReport'
           sourceCompatibility: 1.8
           sourceSets: SourceSet container
           splitsDiscoveryTaskDebug: task ':app:splitsDiscoveryTaskDebug'
           splitsDiscoveryTaskDebugAndroidTest: task ':app:splitsDiscoveryTaskDebugAndroidTest'
           splitsDiscoveryTaskProfile: task ':app:splitsDiscoveryTaskProfile'
           splitsDiscoveryTaskRelease: task ':app:splitsDiscoveryTaskRelease'
           standardOutputCapture: org.gradle.internal.logging.services.DefaultLoggingManager@79cd4052
           state: project state 'EXECUTED'
           status: integration
           subprojects: []
           targetCompatibility: 1.8
           tasks: task set
           test: task ':app:test'
           testDebugUnitTest: task ':app:testDebugUnitTest'
           testProfileUnitTest: task ':app:testProfileUnitTest'
           testReleaseUnitTest: task ':app:testReleaseUnitTest'
           testReportDir: O:\flutter projects\shout\build\app\reports\tests
           testReportDirName: tests
           testResultsDir: O:\flutter projects\shout\build\app\test-results
           testResultsDirName: test-results
           transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug: task ':app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug'
           transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebugAndroidTest: task ':app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebugAndroidTest'
           transformClassesWithDexBuilderForProfile: task ':app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForProfile'
           transformClassesWithPreDexForRelease: task ':app:transformClassesWithPreDexForRelease'
           transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebug: task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebug'
           transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebugAndroidTest: task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebugAndroidTest'
           transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForProfile: task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForProfile'
           transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug: task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'
           transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebugAndroidTest:
task
':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebugAndroidTest'
           transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForProfile: task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForProfile'
           transformDexWithDexForRelease: task ':app:transformDexWithDexForRelease'
           transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug: task ':app:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug'
           transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForDebugAndroidTest: task ':app:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForDebugAndroidTest'
           transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForProfile: task ':app:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForProfile'
           transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease: task ':app:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease'
           transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug: task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'
           transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebugAndroidTest: task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebugAndroidTest'
           transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebugUnitTest: task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebugUnitTest'
           transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForProfile: task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForProfile'
           transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForProfileUnitTest: task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForProfileUnitTest'
           transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease: task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease'
           transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForReleaseUnitTest: task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForReleaseUnitTest'
           uninstallAll: task ':app:uninstallAll'
           uninstallDebug: task ':app:uninstallDebug'
           uninstallDebugAndroidTest: task ':app:uninstallDebugAndroidTest'
           uninstallProfile: task ':app:uninstallProfile'
           uninstallRelease: task ':app:uninstallRelease'
           validateSigningDebug: task ':app:validateSigningDebug'
           validateSigningDebugAndroidTest: task ':app:validateSigningDebugAndroidTest'
           validateSigningProfile: task ':app:validateSigningProfile'
           validateSigningRelease: task ':app:validateSigningRelease'
           version: unspecified
           writeDebugApplicationId: task ':app:writeDebugApplicationId'
           writeProfileApplicationId: task ':app:writeProfileApplicationId'
           writeReleaseApplicationId: task ':app:writeReleaseApplicationId'

           BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
           1 actionable task: 1 executed [  +44 ms] C:\Users\shijo\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\27.0.3\aapt
dump badging build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk [   +8 ms] Exit code 0
from:
C:\Users\shijo\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\27.0.3\aapt
dump badging build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk [        ] package:
name='com.example.shout' versionCode='1' versionName='1.0'
platformBuildVersionName=''
           sdkVersion:'16'
           targetSdkVersion:'27'
           uses-permission: name='android.permission.INTERNET'
           application-label:'shout'
           application-icon-160:'res/mipmap-mdpi-v4/ic_launcher.png'
           application-icon-240:'res/mipmap-hdpi-v4/ic_launcher.png'
           application-icon-320:'res/mipmap-xhdpi-v4/ic_launcher.png'
           application-icon-480:'res/mipmap-xxhdpi-v4/ic_launcher.png'
           application-icon-640:'res/mipmap-xxxhdpi-v4/ic_launcher.png'
           application: label='shout' icon='res/mipmap-mdpi-v4/ic_launcher.png'
           application-debuggable
           launchable-activity: name='com.example.shout.MainActivity'  label='' icon=''
           feature-group: label=''
             uses-feature: name='android.hardware.faketouch'
             uses-implied-feature: name='android.hardware.faketouch' reason='default feature for all apps'
           main
           supports-screens: 'small' 'normal' 'large' 'xlarge'
           supports-any-density: 'true'
           locales: '--_--'
           densities: '160' '240' '320' '480' '640'
           native-code: 'arm64-v8a' 'x86' 'x86_64' [   +9 ms] C:\Users\shijo\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb -s
437122857d74 logcat -v time -t 1 [ +100 ms] Exit code 0 from:
C:\Users\shijo\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb -s
437122857d74 logcat -v time -t 1 [   +1 ms] --------- beginning of
main
           05-17 15:03:50.317 I/XiaomiFirewall( 1991): firewall pkgName:com.UCMobile.intl, result:0x0 [   +9 ms]
C:\Users\shijo\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb -s
437122857d74 logcat -v time [ +433 ms] DependencyChecker: nothing is
modified after 2018-05-17 15:02:43.000. [   +5 ms]
C:\Users\shijo\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb version
[  +17 ms] Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.39
           Version 0.0.1-4500957
           Installed as C:\Users\shijo\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb.EXE [  
+3 ms] C:\Users\shijo\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb start-server

    [  +14 ms] Building APKez enable-background-compilation true --ez
    enable-dart-profiling true --ez enable-checked-mode true
    com.example.shout/com.example.shout.MainActivity [ +984 ms]
    Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.RUN flg=0x20000000
    cmp=com.example.shout/.MainActivity (has extras) } [   +1 ms]
    Waiting
```

for observatory port to be available...

Comment: What's the output of `flutter run -v` and `flutter doctor`

Comment: flutter doctor.. no issues found

Comment: You could still add the output to your question and the output of `flutter run -v`.

Comment: i have updated the answer. check the video also in the question.

Comment: You use `master` channel, but an old version. Run `flutter upgrade` to get a newer version. Still no output from `flutter fun -v`

Comment: i did flutter upgrade..but didnt work.. i have updated the question

Comment: please check the video also

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem with redmi 4 ..i dint figure out the answer yet. but its working fine in aother devices.